Earbuds functional operations
In Windows I used to  press and hold my right or left earbud to increase or decrease the volume but on ubuntu LTS 24.04 I can't

Please at least tell us what earbuds you’re trying to use!

well I cannot use the function on both of them the right one to increase and the left one to decrease and my earbuds are Edifier TWS1 Pro
